# how to unset firebase cloud functions environment variable

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I have tried using command line `functions:config:unset es.tipsinstitue.type` as it is given here [Environment Configuration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env). But this does not work for me. It gives me following exception.

```
 The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Please help me.

Comment: More broadly, any time you use a Firebase Functions from the command line (or indeed most Firebase commands in general), you need to prefix with `firebase`, as that's the system command being run.  In your case, you just needed to run `firebase functions:config:unset es.tipsinstitue.type`.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Don't know whether it is documentation bug or not. Use `firebase functions:config:unset es.tipsinstitue.type`  instead of `functions:config:unset es.tipsinstitue.type`. This will remove your environment variable

Comment: @Cabuxa.Mapache, you can unset multiple keys like this: 
`firebase functions:config:unset key1 key2`