# Unset firebase cloud functions environment variable no updating

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I am trying to update my **environment config in firebase** but somehow seem to be missing something, as the **values are not updated.**

I have unset the key like so:

```
firebase functions:config:unset admin_chat_id
```

I have then deploy this unset like so:

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

Only to check the my config with

```
firebase functions:config:get
```

and **receiving the same set of keys**. I did wait 30 seconds, I waited 5 minutes. I have also checked that I am logged in with firebase. As I don't receive an error message and I don't know where to check the config file in the firebase online console, I am a bit lost.

Could anyone assist?

[This issues around firebase unset is **not relevant as it is syntax related**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45820280/how-to-unset-firebase-cloud-functions-environment-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had missed the fact that admin_chat_id was nested under service. Thus unsetting "admin_chat_id" resulted in unsetting a non-existing value. The correct solution is to use the full path: "service.admin_chat_id".